# Responsive iframe inside a bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's a stripped down example: http://jsbin.com/rewezitamu/1/edit?html,css,output

Notice that the  does not display any content.

If I set `position: inherit` on the .embed-responsive, then it works, but it also covers up the tabs.

Comment: What does "works" mean? What's the problem? Please edit your post to make that more clear without requiring a trip to another website.

Comment: You need to give the iframe a container with height or it collapses to 0. You could also force a min-height on the iframe itself.

Comment: @isherwood I'll try to clarify the post, but the iframe doesn't display

Comment: @isherwood I guess I was trying to avoid specifying an absolute pixel height, hence a "responsive"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the other required Bootstrap responsive embed class.

```
div class="... embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
```

[**JSbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/besuqogeca/2/edit?html,css,output)

Could also use `embed-responsive-4by3`, or you could create your own aspect ratio by specifying any bottom padding value with a new CSS class.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed